# Trojan alert on my phone, real or fake?

Tags: samsung, notifications, hardware, google

so this pop-up appears even though I'm not doing anything and not even on the net 
and it has a background of google sometimes and it says that 'google has detected viruses' on my phone and battery and such out of no where 
and somehow now whenever I click on an app before launching it , it takes me to the app store to download an app  mainly games.

This pop up appears saying there's a virus or trojan on my phone.

[image]

Other info: Galaxy S5, battery keeps dying out of nowhere 
even though I'm not on the web or using the phone.

I even get a notification sound from my phone when it's locked. How to get rid of it?

Comment: You could have tried with [reverse image search](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&tbs=simg:CAESjAEaiQELEKjU2AQaAggKDAsQsIynCBpiCmAIAxIooROWE_1cHkBOYE5ITgAjHHZ8IyB2DPck9wD-EPcw90DPUNMM0yj3IPRowU7rQocAKIAqQgS8coJTwbCvjZ-Ffu_1ajwLPWKv8IC1dw9WbzrMQOxx_1JopJiduUbIAMMCxCOrv4IGgoKCAgBEgRHUf4_1DA&q=android+virus+detected+&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHq5vh-YjLAhXQCI4KHVi8DwgQsw4IKQ&biw=1366&bih=650#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=%22android%22+%22virus+detected%22). And the popup notes "*Trojan*" which is **vastly** different from a **virus**.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the classic "Warning! Your device is infected" scam that tries to push you to buy an overpriced and ineffective "antivirus". (The message is in fact a JavaScript alert hosted at the website mentioned in the header, and there's no way it could have scanned your phone and detected a virus.)

[You can find here more info about this particular malware.](http://blog.jasonsamuels.net/post/72183587582/this-is-what-android-malware-looks-like)

However, the fact that this message keeps appearing on your phone makes me think that your phone has indeed some malware that hijacked your browser.  Download and install a legitimate Android antivirus, for instance [Avast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity&hl=en) which is the top-rated one.